# Does categorical data encoding methods effect the output of the machine learning model drastically?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on this dataset:
[Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrZ9h.png)

The dataset has been split into training (6509, 10) and test set (2787, 10). The categorical features contain 111, 761, 23, 10, 55 categories respectively. I am using RandomForestRegressor model in both the cases.

1. In the first case I used pd.get_dummies to encode categorical features. The R^2 score and Mean Squared Error was 0.33 & 64.14 respectively.
2. In the second case I used LeaveOneOutEncoder. The R^2 score and Mean Squared Error in this case was 0.95 & 8.1 respectively.

My question is can changing the encoding method improve results this drastically or did I make some mistake, and something is wrong with my model?

1. Code for pd_dummies:

```
dummies_train = pd.get_dummies(boats_train)
dummies_test = pd.get_dummies(boats_test)

dummies_test = dummies_test.reindex(columns=dummies_train.columns, fill_value=0)

X_train, y_train = dummies_train.drop('Number of views last 7 days', axis=1).values, \
                   dummies_train['Number of views last 7 days'].values

X_test, y_test = dummies_test.drop('Number of views last 7 days', axis=1).values, \
                 dummies_test['Number of views last 7 days'].values
```

2. Code for LeaveOneOutEncoder

```
cols = ['Boat Type','Manufacturer','Type','Material','Country']
encoder = LeaveOneOutEncoder(return_df=True)

X_train = encoder.fit_transform(boats_train[cols], boats_train['Number of views last 7 days'])
X_train = pd.concat([X_train_loo, boats_train[['Price', 'Year Built', 'Length', 'Width']]], axis=1)

X_test = encoder.transform(boats_test[cols], boats_test['Number of views last 7 days'])
X_test = pd.concat([X_test, boats_test[['Price', 'Year Built', 'Length', 'Width']]], axis=1)

X_train, y_train = X_train_loo.values, boats_train['Number of views last 7 days'].values
X_test, y_test = X_test_loo.values, boats_test['Number of views last 7 days'].values
```

3. RandomForestRegressor

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=SEED, shuffle=True)
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
params = {"n_estimators": np.arange(20, 200),
          "max_depth": np.arange(2, 13),
          "min_samples_split": np.arange(2, 10),
          "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1, 12),
          "ccp_alpha": [0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2],
          }
rf_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, params, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=kf, random_state=SEED)
rf_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tree models do process one hot encoding somewhat worse, however:

- you don't do `drop_first`, and redundant columns could have a negative impact on model variance;
- `pd.get_dummies()` results may be incosistent if the set of categories in your train and test sets happen to differ.